# Word2Vec word containing numeric values

Tags: tensorflow, tokenize, word2vec

When I am adding sentences to Word2Vec model it seems to remove the words which end or start with numeric values, for example "ISO 9001" is returned as "ISO ", I've guessing it's something simple...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any code?  There is preprocessing happening at some point obviously but you're not helping us to help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you already answered your question in the tags you gave to this question. Most likely your tokenizer splits by blank spaces, and leaves out numbers. If you paste the tokenize code you use here we will be able to help you further.

Good luck!